# How to scrape list of YouTube URL's from csv file and output to new csv file with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, youtube

I'm scraping multiple YouTube videos and would like to be able to scrape them at once & load the videos into a csv file with a timestamp of when it was scraped, so I can repeat the process and see the change over time for the metrics listed below.

This is the tutorial I'm using - https://www.promptcloud.com/blog/how-to-scrape-youtube-data-using-python/

I've been trying to follow other recommendations which include parsing the urls with Python's own url abilities and using pandas as a dataframe to import the urls from. None have worked.

Below is the code which I used.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import json
import ast
import json
import os
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

# For ignoring SSL certificate errors

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

# Input from user

url = '[INSERT YOUTUBE VIDEO URL]'

# Making the website believe that you are accessing it using a mozilla browser

req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()

# Creating a BeautifulSoup object of the html page for easy extraction of data.

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
html = soup.prettify('utf-8')
video_details = {}
other_details = {}

for span in soup.findAll('span',attrs={'class': 'watch-title'}):
    video_details['TITLE'] = span.text.strip()

for script in soup.findAll('script',attrs={'type': 'application/ld+json'}):
        channelDesctiption = json.loads(script.text.strip())
        video_details['CHANNEL_NAME'] = channelDesctiption['itemListElement'][0]['item']['name']

for div in soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class': 'watch-view-count'}):
    video_details['NUMBER_OF_VIEWS'] = div.text.strip()

for button in soup.findAll('button',attrs={'title': 'I like this'}):
    video_details['LIKES'] = button.text.strip()

for button in soup.findAll('button',attrs={'title': 'I dislike this'}):
    video_details['DISLIKES'] = button.text.strip()

for span in soup.findAll('span',attrs={'class': 'yt-subscription-button-subscriber-count-branded-horizontal yt-subscriber-count'}):
    video_details['NUMBER_OF_SUBSCRIPTIONS'] = span.text.strip()

hashtags = []
for span in soup.findAll('span',attrs={'class': 'standalone-collection-badge-renderer-text'}):
    for a in span.findAll('a',attrs={'class': 'yt-uix-sessionlink'}):
        hashtags.append(a.text.strip())
video_details['HASH_TAGS'] = hashtags

with open('output_file.html', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(html)

with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
    json.dump(video_details, outfile, ensure_ascii=False,indent=4)

print ('----------Extraction of data is complete. Check json file.----------')
```

I would like to be able to scrape around 150 YouTube videos at once (are contained in a csv column as a list) and output the results into a csv instead of a json file.

Comment: Long story short: Youtube and Google in general don't like to be scraped. They have measures in place to counteract it. Don't expect any tutorial to work forever.

Comment: Thanks @KlausD. I suspected this, but I'm quite new to coding - so had a bit of hope! It does work for one url, is there any way to make it work automatically for the list of url's I have in the csv?

Answer (score 0):

I'll echo what Klaus stated.  Those guys will do everything they can to prevent you from doing these big data dumps.  As you've seen, it works fine for one URL, but the Google engineers certainly have tools in place to prevent repeated calls to their systems.  You could look around for an API, which could easily do this, if it's allowed.  Or, enter a time to hit the site like 1x per 30-60 seconds, or whatever.  Maybe you can set it up to run before you go out to run some errands, or before you go to bed.  At 1x each 60 seconds, it would only take 2.5 hours to finish the job.  Just a thought.

```
import time
while True:
    print("This prints once a minute.")
    time.sleep(60)
```

Put that before your first for loop and see if it does what you want.  They can easily count the number of requests per IP address per time period, and deny any requests over a specified limit, so this concept may or may not work.  Also, you may want to make sure you are not violating the terms and conditions of using YouTube.